# How to write product likes sql query?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table Named `ProductLike` with the fields `ProductId`, `UserId`, and `Like`. When a user likes a product, a record is added to this table with the `UserId` and `ProductId`, as well as the `Like` value (true or false). I want to get a list or group of users who have each product. This is what I have tried so far, but it has errors.

```
SELECT  p.UserId,* 
FROM    ProductLike p WHERE p.ProductId =
        (SELECT pk.ProductId FROM ProductLike pk WHERE pk.ProductLike = 1);
```

Comment: Offtopic-Tip: if you've already an entity "likes" you *probably* don't need to add a field "liked" since if the project is liked, it's contained in that table, if not it's not contained. The only reason for such a flag might be the need to track if user revoked his like (unliked).

Comment: Hint: you might take a look for [JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: It would help if you supplied an example of the input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias the table and join like so:

```
SELECT p.ProductId,p.UserId,p2.UserId 
FROM ProductLike p 
JOIN ProductLike p2 ON p.ProductId = p2.ProductId
WHERE p.[Like]=1 AND p2.[Like]=1 
  AND p.UserId <> p2.UserId
```

This will give you a result set of all users who have "liked" the same product.

**EDIT**: If you wanted to get a result set of all products that have been liked more than once, you could do this:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, COUNT(p.ProductId) 'Likes'
FROM ProductLike p 
WHERE p.[Like]=1 
GROUP BY p.ProductId
HAVING COUNT(p.ProductId) > 1
```